# error expected `;' before

Tags: c++

i cant seem to figure out why it keep saying  expected `;' 
 before "keep_window_open" only on line 28 please help

```
#include<cmath>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
inline void keep_window_open(){char ch;cin>>ch;}


int main()

{
cout<<"Please enter your first name(followed by 'enter'):\n";
string first_name;
cin>>first_name;
cout<<"hello,"<<first_name<<"!\n";
keep_window_open();
return 0;
cout<<"please enter last name:\n";
string Last_name;
cin>> Last_name;
cout<<"hello,"<<first_name<<Last_name<<"!\n"
// this is the only keep_window_open() function that gives me the problem 
keep_window_open();
return 0;  
}
```

Comment: `cout<<"hello,"<<first_name<<Last_name<<"!\n"` is missing a semicolon at the end!

Comment: Read the error message carefully again, and look at what it tries to tell you.

Comment: If the error says a `;` is expected before something, perhaps you could check whether `;` is missing before it (i.e. on the previous non-empty line) before asking for help ;-)

Comment: That `return 0;` after the first `keep_window_open();` is going to take you out of the program before you get to the "please enter last name".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In c++, Your statement should end with `;`

```
cout<<"hello,"<<first_name<<Last_name<<"!\n"
```

Statement Should end with `;`

```
cout<<"hello,"<<first_name<<Last_name<<"!\n";
```

Here is list of statement which requires termination

```
Statement type        Termination required?
==============        =====================
labelled statement              N (a)
expression                      Y
compound statements             N (a)
selection statements            N (a)
iteration statements            N (a) (b)
jump statements                 Y
declaration statement           Y
```

(a) Although it may sometimes appear that these are terminated with a semi-colon, that's not the case. The statement:

if (i == 1) doSomething();
has the semi-colon terminating the inner expression statement, not the compound statement, somthing that should be obvious when you examine the first code segment above that has it inside {} braces.

(b) do requires the semi-colon after the while expression.

Answer (score 0):

Because you forgot the `;` on the line before (the `cout`, which doesn't have a `;` on the end):

Change:

```
cout<<"hello,"<<first_name<<Last_name<<"!\n"
```

to:

```
cout<<"hello,"<<first_name<<Last_name<<"!\n";
```

...and see if things don't go better.